# creando un ejecutable en python en VS code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Me encuentro viendo un video tutorial sobre crear un ejecutable del programa que tengo en python el cual indica que hay que instalar la librería/paquete `pyinstaller` y bueno si lo pude llevar a cabo el problema se me da después de que trato de ejecutar el `pyinstaller nombrearchivo.py`; esto es lo que ejecuto en el cmd como administrador, (previamente ya inicialice el entorno virtual):

```
C:\Users\admin\documents\pythonarch\catalogo> pip installer pyinstaller
(tutorial-env) C:\Users\admin\documents\pythonarch\catalogo>catalogo.spec
```

Según el video tengo que ejecutar el `.spec` para que se genere el `.exe`
pero en el cmd me sale lo siguiente:

```
127 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.7.0
127 INFO: Pyhton: 3.9.7
145 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0
149 INFO: UPX is not available
script 'C:\Users\admin\documents\pythonarch\catalogo\catalogo.pec' not found
```

he buscado información relacionada sin éxito alguno y tengo la esperanza de que alguien haya tenido algún problema similar y me sepa ayudar o que me recomiende algún video tutorial sobre el tema de la creación de ejecutables en python para seguir aprendiendo

Answer (score 0):

Me paso algo similar, pero no con ese tipo de archivo. El error podria ser porque no estas ubicado en la raiz del archivo, por lo cual si tienes un directorio raiz y una carpeta donde se ubica este archivo, debes generar el exe desde la carpeta correcta.
Para generar un exe de un archivo en especifico utiliza:

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

Para generar un exe con mas archivos indicando cual es tu archivo principal:

```
pyinstaller -F main.py
```